# How to concatenate two lists so that elements are in alternative position?

Tags: python, list, function, element

for example:

```
 a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
 b=[7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

then result:

```
c=[1,7,2,8,3,9,4,10,5,11,6,12]
```

How do you concatenate two lists,so that the elements are in alternative positions??

i have tried to link them in to a new list and rearrange but its not coming.
it would be nice if you could tell me the long way(without using built in functions too much).I m new to python and not much is taught in my school.
Thank you.

Comment: a lot of answers have already been given here but I found a much simpler way to do this. `c = [None]*(len(a)+len(b)); c[::2]=a;c[1::2]=b`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just append them with a for loop, assuming they're the same length:

```
c = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    c.append(a[i])
    c.append(b[i])
```

Comment: enumerate would be a much better idea

Comment: He clearly said he was a beginner, otherwise I would use a better approach.

Comment: beginner or not enumerate is the way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

for uneven size lists in python 3 you can use `filter` and `zip_longest` filtering `None`:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

from itertools import chain, zip_longest

print(list(filter(None.__ne__ ,chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(a,b)))))
[1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4, 10, 5, 11, 6, 12, 13]
```

Using python2 use a list comp and filter None's with `ele is not None`:

```
print([ ele for ele in chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(a, b)) if ele is not None])
```

If you may have `None` as a  value in your lists use a custom sentinel value, using that as the `fillvalue` in `zip_longest`:

```
my_sent = object()
print([ ele for ele in chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(a, b,fillvalue=my_sent)) if ele is not my_sent])
```

Comment: I would recommend using a different sentinel value than `None`, for ex: `object()`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, yes if there were None's potentially in the list, I will add though.

Comment: `(None.__ne__ )` causes 'DeprecationWarning:'. Removing the `__ne__` works.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> b = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> [x for xs in zip(a, b) for x in xs]
[1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4, 10, 5, 11, 6, 12]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> b = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> print list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b)))
```